# pandas read_csv parse header as string type but i want integer

Tags: python, pandas

for example, csv file is as below ,(1,2,3) is header!

```
1,2,3
0,0,0
```

I read csv file using pd.read_csv and print

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
print(df[1])
```

it occur error `key error:1`

it seems like that `read_csv` parse header as string..

is there any way using integer type in dataframe column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think more general is cast to columns names to `integer` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)
```

Another way is first get only first column and use parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = np.array(next(reader)).astype(int)

#another way
#i = pd.read_csv("file.csv", nrows=0).columns.astype(int)
print (i)
[1 2 3]

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", names=i, skiprows=1)
print (df.columns)
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: your general method is very good. and I facing another problem, my real dataframe column is multi index! and df.columns.level[0].astype(int) occur error TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.. is there good way?

Comment: I think need `df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0).astype(int), df.columns.get_level_values(1)]`

Comment: @이승훈 No, I think a better option would be using `df.columns.set_levels`.

Comment: @이승훈 - Glad can help!

Answer (score 3):

Skip the header column using `skiprows=1` and `header=None`. This automatically loads in a dataframe with integer headers starting from `0` onwards.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=1, header=None).rename(columns=lambda x: x + 1)
```

```
df    
   1  2  3
0  0  0  0
```

The `rename` call is optional, but if you want your headers to start from `1`, you may keep it in.

---

If you have a `MultiIndex`, use `set_levels` to set just the 0<sup>th</sup> level to integer:

```
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(
     df.columns.get_level_values(0).astype(int), level=0
)
```

Comment: `set_levels` is a great option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set_axis` in conjunction with a `lambda` and `pd.Index.map`

Consider a csv that looks like:

```
1,1,2,2
a,b,a,b
1,3,5,7
0,2,4,6
```

Read it like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0, 1])
df

   1     2   
   a  b  a  b
0  1  3  5  7
1  0  2  4  6
```

You can pipeline the column setting with integers in the first level like:

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.map(lambda i: (int(i[0]), i[1])), axis=1, inplace=False)

   1     2   
   a  b  a  b
0  1  3  5  7
1  0  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way using integer type in dataframe column?

I find this quite elegant:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').rename(columns=int)
```

Note that `int` here is the built-in *function* [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Elegant, indeed!